# Uniform distribution in arc4random_uniform and PCG

Tags: c, random, uniform-distribution

Both `arc4random_uniform` from `OpenBSD` and the `PCG` library by `Melissa O'Neill` have a similar looking algorithm to generate a non biased unsigned integer value up to an excluding upper bound.

```
inline uint64_t
pcg_setseq_64_rxs_m_xs_64_boundedrand_r(struct pcg_state_setseq_64 * rng,
                                        uint64_t bound) {
    uint64_t threshold = -bound % bound;
    for (;;) {
        uint64_t r = pcg_setseq_64_rxs_m_xs_64_random_r(rng);
        if (r >= threshold)
            return r % bound;
    }
}
```

Isn't `-bound % bound` always zero? If it's always zero then why have the loop and the if statement at all?

The `OpenBSD` has the same thing too.

```
uint32_t
arc4random_uniform(uint32_t upper_bound)
{
    uint32_t r, min;

    if (upper_bound < 2)
        return 0;

    /* 2**32 % x == (2**32 - x) % x */
    min = -upper_bound % upper_bound;

    /*
     * This could theoretically loop forever but each retry has
     * p > 0.5 (worst case, usually far better) of selecting a
     * number inside the range we need, so it should rarely need
     * to re-roll.
     */
    for (;;) {
        r = arc4random();
        if (r >= min)
            break;
    }

    return r % upper_bound;
}
```

Apple's version of `arc4random_uniform` has a different version of it.

```
u_int32_t
arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t upper_bound)
{
    u_int32_t r, min;

    if (upper_bound < 2)
        return (0);

#if (ULONG_MAX > 0xffffffffUL)
    min = 0x100000000UL % upper_bound;
#else
    /* Calculate (2**32 % upper_bound) avoiding 64-bit math */
    if (upper_bound > 0x80000000)
        min = 1 + ~upper_bound;     /* 2**32 - upper_bound */
    else {
        /* (2**32 - (x * 2)) % x == 2**32 % x when x <= 2**31 */
        min = ((0xffffffff - (upper_bound * 2)) + 1) % upper_bound;
    }
#endif

    /*
     * This could theoretically loop forever but each retry has
     * p > 0.5 (worst case, usually far better) of selecting a
     * number inside the range we need, so it should rarely need
     * to re-roll.
     */
    for (;;) {
        r = arc4random();
        if (r >= min)
            break;
    }

    return (r % upper_bound);
}
```

Comment: `-bound % bound` is not mathematically −bound % bound. Because `bound` is `uint64_t`, it is (2^64 − bound) % bound. It is calculating the residue of 2^64 modulo bound to peel off that amount from the 2^64 interval to leave just a multiple of bound.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, so given the value 3, the correct expression in C would be `(uint64_t)-3 % 3`?

Comment: The expression `-bound % bound` is correct because the type of `bound` is `uint64_t`, so the `-` is performed modulo 2^64. With `-3`, the `-` is done with `int` arithmetic. So then a cast to `uint64_t` would be necessary to wrap it modulo 2^64. This cast is unnecessary with `-bound % bound`. (Except in a C implementation where `int` is wider than 64 bits, because then `bound` would be promoted to `int`. However, I do not believe there are any such C implementations in ordinary use.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `bound` is a `uint64_t`, `-bound` is evaluated modulo 2<sup>64</sup>. The result is 2<sup>64</sup>−`bound`, not −`bound`.

Then `-bound % bound` calculates the residue of 2<sup>64</sup>−`bound` modulo `bound`. This equals the residue of 2<sup>64</sup> modulo `bound`.

By setting `threshold` to this and rejecting numbers that are less than `threshold`, the routine reduces the accepted interval to 2<sup>64</sup>−`threshold` numbers. The result is an interval that has a number of numbers that is a multiple of `bound`.

From a number `r` selected in that interval, the routine returns `r % bound`. Due to the trimming of the interval, there are an equal number of occurrences of each residue, so the result has no bias for any residue over any other.